# How to get and return each last character of array to be in uppercase using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have the following `array` variable, I want to return the given array where each of element's last character to be in `Uppercase` using javascript, I have tried like below, but I am getting `undefined` unfortunately, Could you please anyone help me to get the desired output like below. Thanks in advance.

Desired Output: `[onE, twO, threE, fouR]`

```
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

var res = arr.map((item) => {
    item.substr(arr.length) + item.charAt(arr.length -1).toUpperCase();
});
console.log(res);//[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Comment: you have to return inside map

Comment: `return item.substr(0,item.length-1) + item.charAt(item.length -1).toUpperCase();` . also its not arr.length but item.length

Comment: @cmgchess oh Yes, got it, and the above is working fine. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

you are missing a return statement:

```
var res = arr.map((item) => {
    return item.slice(0,-1)+item.slice(-1).toUpperCase()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also skip curly brackets and *return* keyword:

```
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

const res = arr.map(item => 
    item.substring(0, item.length - 1) +
    item.charAt(item.length - 1).toUpperCase()
)

console.log(res);
```

Also notice that *String.prototype.substr* is mentioned as deprecated (you can use substring instead).